# Why isn't SQL SMO returning my View?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, powershell-2.0, smo

I've got a view named `foo` in schema `bar` that I want to retrieve a reference to. Why? Because I'm going to alter the `TextBody` property in a script.

I'm trying to retrieve a reference to the view using SMO. I've tried two different methods so far; one method is returning a null value for the View, and the other is giving a couple odd, error message.

**Example 1 (Instantiating the View)**

All the values on the object are null, so I guess instantiating a `View` object is only meant for creating a new View.

```
$ViewTest = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.View -ArgumentList $ServerSmo.Databases["dbname"], 'foo', 'bar';
```

(note that `$ServerSmo` is a Smo.Server object)

**Example 2 (Indexer notation)**

This *should* work. Based on the `ViewCollection`'s Item indexer: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms218327.aspx)

```
$ViewTest = $ServerSmo.Databases["dbname"].Views['foo', 'bar'];
```

This example is the one that's giving me a couple weird error messages. It's returning a message saying: `To accomplish this action, set property AnsiNullsStatus.` If I set the `AnsiNullsStatus` property to `$true`, then I get this message: `To accomplish this action, set property BodyStartIndex.` The `View` doesn't even have a property named that.

Now, I have two more examples that work:

**Example 3 (Item() Indexer Method)**

Calling the indexer as a method instead of using indexer notation seems to work just fine.

```
$ViewTest = $ServerSmo.Databases["dbname"].Views.Item('foo', 'bar');
```

**Example 4 (Where-Object)**

Enumerating all the `View` objects to the PowerShell pipeline, and then filtering using the Where-Object cmdlet seems to work just fine, but it's inefficient and ugly.

```
$ViewTest = $ServerSmo.Databases["dbname"].Views | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -eq 'foo' and $_.Schema -eq 'bar' };
```

---

So after writing all of this, I guess my question more or less comes down to: why doesn't the Indexer notation work as in Example #2?

UPDATE: I wrote some C# code, which seems to retrieve the View just fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new Server(".");
            var db = server.Databases["dbname"];
            var view = db.Views["foo", "bar"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example #2 works for me (in v3), I can change the View TextBody with this:

```
$ViewTest = $ServerSmo.Databases['dbname'].Views['foo','bar']
$ViewTest.TextBody='foo'
$ViewTest.Alter()
```

In v2 $ViewTest is a collection of System.Object[] so I had to index it to set the bosy and call the alert method

```
$ViewTest = $ServerSmo.Databases['dbname'].Views['foo','bar']
$ViewTest[0].TextBody='foo'
$ViewTest[0].Alter()
```

Comment: Really? That is exactly what's returning a $null [Object[]] for me.

Comment: Yes, I have just confirmed it, $view is Object[]

Comment: But mine is $null, whereas yours actually contains a SMO View? I would expect that calling GetType() should return `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.View]`

Comment: Yup, that's the I get when I pipe to gm, wwhich unravels the collection. Getting the type on the collection itself returns System.Object[]

Comment: I think this is a bug in PowerShell .. I posted some C# code that works just fine for me.